# How to see CONNECT tunnel information when issuing requests from composer in Fiddler?

Tags: ssl, fiddler, amazon-connect, fiddler-everywhere

When I use intercept requests in Fiddler, I can inspect CONNECT tunnels. But when I try to issue request from Fiddler's composer, there is no CONNECT session. Is it possible to inspect CONNECTs when issuing requests from Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONNECT` is a special protocol command that is only used in combination with a http proxy. If a proxy receives a CONNECT command from the client this means "please establish a connection to the endpoint included in the CONNECT command".

If you use Fiddler composer the request is sent directly to the server without using Fiddler as a proxy. Thus you won't see a CONNECT command. If you want to see a CONNECT request then you have to use an external tool that uses Fiddler as https proxy.

Comment: Ok, but is there any possibility to see the handshake details between Fiddler and server? For example, I want to see which ciphers does Fiddler provide to server.

Comment: @Maxim At least in Fiddler Classic I don't see a way to display TLS handshake details. If you need those details I would use Wireshark. As Fiddler Classic is a .Net program used TLS version and ciphers are defined by the used Windows version.